# Button from UITableViewController sends data to detailViewController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a problem that I cannot wrap my head around.. You cannot create a button action in a UITableViewController.. So I tried to just control + drag from the button to the detailtableViewController and pressed push.. But when I use prepareForSegue and I then click on the button it should send the button text to a string in the detailtableViewController, but sometimes it's not the correct name, because there are multiple cells in the tableView and the name is not always the same..

What I need it to do is, when you click the button "Button:
[image]

It should go to this detailtableViewController:
[image]

With the name that is set as text to the Button.
The variable that should receive the name of the button is called viaSegue and it is a string.

My UITableViewController:

```
    class feedTableViewController: UITableViewController, PostCellDelegate {



        @IBOutlet weak var loadingSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
        @IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!


        var sendName = "No name"
        var facebookProfileUrl = ""
        var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
        var updates = [Sweet]()
        var gottenUserId : Bool? = false
        var gottenUserIdWorkout : Bool? = false

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let logoImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 32))
            logoImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

            let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
            logoImage.image = logo
            self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImage



            loadingSpinner.startAnimating()


            if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

                let userId = user.uid


                let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

                // Refer to your own Firebase storage
                let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("**********")

                let profilePicRef = storageRef.child(userId+"/profile_pic.jpg")

                // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
                profilePicRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 300 * 300) { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        print("Unable to download image")
                    } else {
                        // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                        // ... let islandImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
                        if (data != nil){
                            self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            self.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = self.profilePicture.frame.size.width/2
                            self.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true

                        }
                    }
                }


            }

            dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items")
            startObersvingDB()

            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 205
        }

        func startObersvingDB() {
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedByChild("date").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
                var newUpdates = [Sweet]()

                for update in snapshot.children {
                    let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                    newUpdates.append(updateObject)

                }

                self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }) { (error: NSError) in
                print(error.description)
            }
        }





        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }












        // MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return updates.count
        }


        protocol PostCellDelegate: class {
            func postCell(postCell: PostCell, didTouchUpInside button: UIButton)
        }


        func postCell(postCell: PostCell, didTouchUpInside button: UIButton) {
            let identifier = "toDetailtableViewController"
            let username = postCell.nameButton.titleLabel?.text
            performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: username)
        }






        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// Lots of stuff happening here
```

My custom cell:

```
class updateTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var updateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var hand: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameButton: UIButton!


    weak var delegate: PostCellDelegate?

    var pathDB : String!
    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var gottenUserId : Bool? = false
    var sendNameCell = "No name here"




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func likeTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        //print(pathDB)
        checkClickOnLikeButton()


    }


    @IBAction func didTouchUpInsideButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.postCell(self, didTouchUpInside: button)
    }




    func checkClickOnLikeButton() {
        let dataPathen = self.pathDB
        // print(dataPathen)


        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

            let userId = user.uid



            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                self.gottenUserId = snapshot.value![userId] as? Bool

                // print(self.gottenUserId)

                if self.gottenUserId == true {
                    print("Der er trykket high five før")
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").child(userId).removeValue()
                    let greyButtonColor = UIColor(red: 85/255, green: 85/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    self.likeButton.setTitleColor(greyButtonColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    self.hand.image = UIImage(named: "high.png")
                } else {
                    print("Der er IKKE trykket like før")
                    let quoteString = [userId: true]
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").updateChildValues(quoteString)
                    let blueButtonColor = UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 45/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    self.likeButton.setTitleColor(blueButtonColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    self.hand.image = UIImage(named: "highfive.png")
                }


                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



        }

    }









}
```

Comment: add your `prepareforsegue` method in question and are you calling `performsegue` on button's click ?

Comment: I added the prepareforsegue.. No, because I have a custom cell class and I cannot get data from that class when the data that should be send is in my UITableViewController? and I cannot use performsegue in a custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created a custom class for the cell containing the `Button`, you must create an `@IBAction` for the `didTouchUpInside` event. You must also create a segue directly from the `UITableViewController` to the `detailtableViewController` (so not from a button or a view, from one view controller to the other). You will need to give this segue an identifier since we're going to be performing it manually.

Once you've hooked up the `@IBAction` in the cell, we need a way of performing the segue from the cell. To do this, we need a reference to the `UITableViewController`. We could get it using delegates or maybe responders, recently I've been using responders.

*Delegate*

Create a protocol for your `UITableViewController` to conform to.

```
protocol PostCellDelegate: class {
    func postCell(_ postCell: PostCell, didTouchUpInside button: UIButton)
}
```

Create a delegate variable in your custom cell class call it's `didTouchUpInside` method from button's `@IBAction` for that event.

```
weak var delegate: PostCellDelegate?

@IBAction func didTouchUpInsideButton() {
    delegate?.postCell(self, didTouchUpInside: button)
}
```

Now in your `UITableViewController`, you must conform to the delegate and set the delegate of the cells in the `cellForRowAt` method.

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController, PostCellDelegate {

    //...

    // MARK: PostCellDelegate

    func postCell(_ postCell: PostCell, didTouchUpInside button: UIButton) {
        let identifier = "toDetailtableViewController"
        let username = postCell.button.titleLabel?.text
        performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: username)
    }

    //...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    //...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch (segue.destination, sender) {
        case let (controller as detailtableViewController, username as String):
            controller.usernameTextField.text = username
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you time Callam! I used your code and got some errors.. I followed your post, so do you know what could be wrong here? Updated your answer with pictures of where my errors are, so you could see :-)

Comment: You need to change the names of the postcell class since you didn't say what the name of your custom cell class was

Comment: Let me know what code you want and I will add it :)